# Filter function for less +F

Tags: less-unix

When watching a growing log file with e.g. "less -iS +F service.log" I want
to limit the display to lines matching a certain pattern.

I tried something like

```
less +F service.log | grep <pattern> | less +F
```

which doesn't work. Also

```
cat < service.log | grep <pattern> | less +F
```

doesn't do what I want. It looks like the input is already closed and
less doesn't show changes.

How can I limit the display to lines matching a certain pattern?

Answer (score 31):

This question is ages old, but I still think it's worth adding a solution.
Instead of trying to grep first and then use less, what about using *filtering inside less*?

In brief:

1. `use less +F` on your file
2. `CTRL-C` to temporarily break the "following" action
3. Type `&` and your pattern to enable filtering
4. Issue `+F` to re-enable the "following" action

More details on this answer on the [Unix&Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179240/107799)

Comment: thaaanks !! I found the Linux stackexchange and didn't understand it. Glad to find your step by step explanation !! :)

Comment: To do this directly from the command line: `less '+&<pattern>^MF' service.log` where the `^M` is obtained by typing ctrl-v and then enter

Comment: From bash, without the C-v (quoted-insert): `less $'+&<pattern>\nF' service.log`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't yet worked out how to do this without a temp file, but here is a script that demonstrates a functional `grep`-filtered `less +F` (which cleans up its temp file). I call it `lessf`.

One of the key elements is the `--line-buffered` argument to `grep` that permits `tail` output to continue to flow through the pipeline (the `unbuffer` command provided by `expect` provides similar functionality for any program).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
LOGFILE=$1
shift
PATTERN=$@
TEMP_DIR=/tmp/lesstmp
TEMP_FILE="$TEMP_DIR/$(basename $LOGFILE)"
[ ! -d $TEMP_DIR ] && mkdir $TEMP_DIR
trap 'rm -rf "$TEMP_DIR"; exit' INT TERM EXIT
( tail -f "$LOGFILE" | grep --line-buffered $PATTERN ) > "$TEMP_FILE" | less +F "$TEMP_FILE"
trap - INT TERM EXIT
```

Example usage:

`lessf /var/log/system.log foobar`

`lessf /var/log/system.log -v nobar`

Comment: I'd like to point out how using the pipe between tail|grep and less +F makes sure that Ctrl-C will kill them all in one go. I had something similar but using background jobs, it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind spawning and tearing down a couple of processes each line, use a read while loop

```
tail -f filename.log|while read line; do echo $line | grep pattern; done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tail -f service.log | grep <pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks for pondering my question though this is not exactly what I want.

I want to have "less" functionality, i.e. scrolling, searching, hightlighting within the resulting output.

Something like "tail -f service.log | grep <pattern> | less +F" which unfortunalely doesn't do it.

Answer (score -1):

The solution seemed simply

```
LESSOPEN='|grep <pattern> %s' less +F service.log
```

but less doesn't continue to read new lines from the growing log file.

Comment: my original answer from 2009 doesn't seem to be valid anymore, i.e. the simple solution does watch for a growing log file